# WP7 with visual studio -- All my apps are getting the same schema messages

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, schema

Every time I create a WP7 app, I get the following two messages:

```
"Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment:Deployment'.
```

and

```
"Could not find schema information for the element 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment:Deployment.Parts'.
```

As far as I can tell, the apps are working OK.  But the messages are annoying.  How can I get rid of them?

Answer (score 0):

In your `Properties` folder, you should have a file clled AppManifest.xml with the following contents:

```
<Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007/deployment"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Deployment.Parts>
    </Deployment.Parts>
</Deployment>
```

You should also have a reference to System.Windows[.dll] in your app.

Comment: I do have have both of those things.  But the messages are still there.